# Highlighting points on a scatter plot that are in top 5% deviating furthest from the fit (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight, linear-regression

I want to highlight points on a xy-scatter plot (plotted using ggplot) that are above certain threshold of the fit line (plotted using geom_smooth and lm). A good example of the threshold can be top 10% points deviating furthest from the regression line. How can I get it done in R?

Thanks.
DP

Comment: Possible. If you're talking about regular `lm` linear models, check out `?residuals` and `?quantile`. Then, in long format, use an indicator variable to reflect the top and bottom 5 or 10%, and something like `aes(..., color=indicator.variable)` in your `ggplot` call. For more, please add a reproducible data analysis example.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Yes, I use lm linear model. I will read more on your suggestions.